# Вывод записей из БД в ListView

Tags: android, android-studio

Есть такой код в общих чертах, который работает и выводит найденные записи из БД в обычный TextView.

Это только метод, который выводит записи в общих чертах, все работает.

```html
public void search() {
 String str = textEdit.getText().toString().trim();
 String query = "Запрос";
     
 Cursor cursor = db.database.rawQuery(query, null);
 try {
  if (cursor.getCount() != 0) {
   while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(TableEntry.COLUMN_COL1);
    String col1 = cursor.getString(index );
    txtView.append(col1);
   }

  }
 } catch (SQLException ex) {
 } finally {
  cursor.close();
 }
}
```

Как можно реализовать так чтобы вывод шел в ListView, чтобы на выходе найденные записи выводились вот так как на картинке[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Есть два варианта:
1. вам нужно сделать 2 xml для item списка и переопределить метод `getItemViewType(int position)`. Там в зависимости от позиции вы будете возвращать тип xml. По четным позициям одна xml, по нечетным другая. 
2. Сделать одну xml, но в методе getView проверять позицию и двигать TextView.
Ну а адаптер должен быть: `SimpleCursorAdapter`

Comment: У меня такой вопрос по ссылке http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/111-urok-52-simplecursoradapter-primer-ispolzovanija.html пишут что SimpleCursorAdapter устаревший и рекомендуют использовать http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/278-urok-136-cursorloader.html. Так на что мне ориентироваться?

Comment: Лучше использовать последний вариант. Т.к. в базе может быть много записей и доставать их в UI потоке не хорошо. Это приведет к тому, что UI повиснет на некоторое время. А второй вариант работает в отдельном потоке.

Answer (score 0):

По видимому вам нужны адаптеры, типо [SimpleCursorAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html).
Вот вам [пример1](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/111-urok-52-simplecursoradapter-primer-ispolzovanija.html), [пример2](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/simplecursoradapter.php).

Comment: Спасибо.. сейчас посмотрю их.